# "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement" - how to insert API json data in mysql with python?

Tags: python, mysql, json

I need to insert the JSON Metrics obtained by the Yandex API into the already created mysql table. The code, json, and error text are below. As far as I understand, the error is not in the correct data format - it is necessary to decompose the data from json into a table, and metrics should be divided into 2 columns

What i get with API and it's json:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "dimensions": [
            {
                "name": "2019-02-03"
            }
        ],
        "metrics": [
            100.0,
            1000.0
        ]
    },
    {
        "dimensions": [
            {
                "name": "2019-02-01"
            }
        ],
        "metrics": [
            200.0,
            2000.0
        ]
    },
    {
        "dimensions": [
            {
                "name": "2019-02-02"
            }
        ],
        "metrics": [
            300.0,
            3000.0
        ]
    }
],
"data_lag": 148,
"max": [
    300.0,
    3000.0
],
"min": [
    100.0,
    1000.0
],
"query": {
    "adfox_event_id": "0",
    "attribution": "Last",
    "auto_group_size": "1",
    "currency": "RUB",
    "date1": "2019-02-01",
    "date2": "2019-02-03",
    "dimensions": [
        "ym:s:date"
    ],
    "filters": "ym:s:lastsignUTMSource=='yandex_market'",
    "group": "Week",
    "ids": [
        COUNTER_ID
    ],
    "limit": 100,
    "metrics": [
        "ym:s:ecommercePurchases",
        "ym:s:ecommerceRevenue"
    ],
    "offline_window": "21",
    "offset": 1,
    "quantile": "50",
    "sort": [
        "-ym:s:ecommercePurchases"
    ]
},
"sample_share": 1.0,
"sample_size": 619636,
"sample_space": 619636,
"sampled": false,
"total_rows": 3,
"total_rows_rounded": false,
"totals": [
    600.0,
    6000.0
]
}
```

Code:

```
import requests
import json
import mysql.connector

headers = {'Authorization': 'OAuth TOKEN'}
ids = {
    'Count_1': COUNTER_ID,
}

body = {
    'metrics': 'ym:s:ecommercePurchases,ym:s:ecommerceRevenue',
    'dimensions': 'ym:s:date',
    'date1': '2019-02-01',
    'date2': '2019-02-03',
    'filters': "ym:s:lastsignUTMSource=='yandex_market'",
    'ids': COUNTER_ID,
    'accuracy': 'full',
}

while True:
  try:
    req = requests.get('https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/data', params=body, headers=headers)
    req.encoding = 'utf-8'  # UTF-8
    #succes\error messages
    #...
    elif req.status_code == 200: #succes message
            print("Report succes") 
            parsed = json.loads(req.text) 
            print (json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True)) #json with hierarchy
            break
    #...

con = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="host_IP",
  user="USER",
  passwd="PWD",
  database="DB_NAME"
)

mycursor = con.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO API_METRIKA(Date, Purchases, Revenue) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)" 

mycursor.executemany(sql, parsed) #inserting api-data into mysql table
print('Вставлено строк:', mycursor.rowcount) #how many rows were inserted

con.commit()  
con.close()
```

Full error text:

ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
    115 print (parsed)
    116 
--> 117 mycursor.executemany(sql, parsed)
    118 
    119 print('Вставлено строк:', mycursor.rowcount)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py in _batch_insert(self, operation, seq_params)
    595                     if psub.remaining != 0:
    596                         raise errors.ProgrammingError(
--> 597                             "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
    598                     #for p in self._process_params(params):
    599                     #    tmp = tmp.replace(b'%s',p,1)

ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: I dont think `VALUES (%s, %s, %s)` actually resolves to something

Comment: @Snackoverflow that's standart - https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: Sure, but I really doubt that `json.loads(req.text)` is correctly structured. Execute expects a list of lists (so 2d list), doesn't look like you're supplying that

Comment: Your JSON is nested and hence needs to be parsed by levels before appending to database table. What values do you need to extract as columns (*Purchases*, *Revenue* with many dates) do not appear in JSON?

Comment: @Parfait i should get like [(2019-02-03,100.0,1000),(2019-02-01,200.0,2000),(2019-02-02,300.0,3000)]  - ready for mysql join

Comment: almost:

`
val1 = []
for day in parsed['data']:
  val = str(day['dimensions'][0]['name']) + ',' + str(day['metrics'][0]) + ',' + str(day['metrics'][1])
  val1.append((val,))`

Comment: got this one:
 [('2019-02-03,100.0,1000'),('2019-02-01,200.0,2000'),('2019-02-02,300.0,3000')]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass specific parameters from the json feed, you need to extract the specific values from tree structure. Currently, you pass *entire* json into `executemany()` call. Also, consider the [`.json()`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) method of response object, avoiding the need of `json.loads()` and even importing the `json` library:

```
parsed = req.json()
...
```

From your posted result, the needed *dimensions* and *metrics* show in *data* list level:

```
for v in parsed["data"]:
   print(v)

# {'metrics': [100.0, 1000.0], 'dimensions': [{'name': '2019-02-03'}]}
# {'metrics': [200.0, 2000.0], 'dimensions': [{'name': '2019-02-01'}]}
# {'metrics': [300.0, 3000.0], 'dimensions': [{'name': '2019-02-02'}]}
```

Therefore, you can create a *vals* list via list comprehension to be passed into `executemany`:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO API_METRIKA (`Date`, `Purchases`, `Revenue`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)" 

# LIST OF TUPLES
vals = [(v['dimensions'][0]['name'],
         v['metrics'][0],
         v['metrics'][1]) for v in parsed["data"]]

# inserting api-data into mysql table
mycursor.executemany(sql, vals)
```

Comment: thank you
And a little correction - `Date`, `Purchases`, `Revenue` should be without ``

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! And in MySQL, backticks escape [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-D) like *Date* or identifiers (i.e., table/column names) with space and special characters. You should not be receiving errors with them.